# synchronized block android

Tags: android, synchronized

I have written some database queries in synchronized method. Ideally if some code is executing inside this code block then other thread should not access this but it does sometimes in my case.

```
   synchronized private void func1 () {
             // printing some log for start 

             // some database code

            // printing log at the end
   }
```

So the log which i have printed at the start prints twice. How to block this thing?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are putting a query in a synchronized block?

Comment: are you calling func1 on multiple instances of the class it's in?

Comment: this is not a synchronized block, it is a synchronized method
a syncrhonized block is of the form
synchronized(lockobject) {
// some code
} ::: Not that it makes any difference to your question, just wante d to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized block uses a lock on the object that calls func1(). If you call func1 from different threads using different objects the situation encountered is possible.

Assuming you have

```
class A {
   synchronized private void func1() {}
   void func2() { func1()}
}
```

And call from 2 different threads new A().func2(), func1() is not thread safe in this case.

If you have only 1 instance of class A in my example than it must work.